# Regex to select the white space before a certain character

Tags: regex

I would like to create a regex that would allow me to select the white space before a comma. 
ie. "Happy birthday, Jimmy" The regex should select the white space 
"Happy()birthday, Jimmy" as it comes before a word/string containing a comma. *noted by the parenthesis.

Comment: nevermind 6 more to go...

Answer (score 7):

You can use [Look Ahead](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2973436/regex-lookahead-lookbehind-and-atomic-groups) to accomplish this.

If you are ok with matching every white space that comes before a comma, then check this out:

[`\s(?=[^,]*,)`](https://regex101.com/r/KXArye/1)

If you only want to match the closest whitespace before the comma, check this out:

[`\s(?=[^,\s]*,)`](https://regex101.com/r/KXArye/2)

---

- `\s` indicated a whitespace character
- `(?=...)` is a positive look ahead, meaning it makes sure its contents follow our matches

  - `[]` groups a set of possible characters to match

    - `[^...]` indicates that it should match with any character other than the contents
  - `[^,\s]` thus looks for any character which is not a whitespace or a comma
  - `[^,\s]*` the `*` tells it to look for zero to as many as possible of these
  - `,` we want to find a comma now that we have found all non-spaces and non-commas

Comment: absolutely fantastic answer! provided different options and clearly explained what to people new to regex could be a very confusing answer as well as a link to another source to learn more about this and other related regex tools. Well done!!!!