# RegEx to select only the white spaces before a certain word

Tags: regex, pcre

I have a long string with lots of HTTP URLs separated by a comma, and I'm trying to create a regular expression to find and replace spaces with %20, but only before "zip" in VSCode. Therefore, spaces after the "zip" should be allowed up to the following URL (before a comma ",").

I've tried using "\s(?=[^zip]*zip)" based on the following question; however, it's not working.

[Regex to select the white space before a certain character](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51274690/regex-to-select-the-white-space-before-a-certain-character)

Sample Text: `http://abcd.com/old file/anotherfile.zip/some contents/sample.txt,http://abcd.com/new file/anotherfile.zip/some more contents/new sample.txt,http://abcd.com/newer file/another file.zip/some more contents/old sample.txt,http://abcd.com/newer file/another file.txt`

Expected Output: `http://abcd.com/old%20file/anotherfile.zip/some contents/sample.txt,http://abcd.com/new%20file/anotherfile.zip/some more contents/new sample.txt,http://abcd.com/newer%20file/another file.zip/some more contents/old sample.txt,http://abcd.com/newer%20file/another%20file.txt`

P.S. The string also contains URLs to files, not inside a zip like the last URL in the above sample. Observe that, with the regular expression, I'm trying to replace the selected space with '%20' whenever there's a space in the path before  "zip" and everywhere when the path doesn't have any zip.

Comment: That should be `\s(?=[^,]*zip\b)` or `\s(?=[^/,]*zip\b)`

Comment: Thanks @WiktorStribiżew, this works "\s(?=[^,]*zip\b)". But, now the URLs with spaces, which doesn't contain zip don't get selected.

Comment: emm, why don't you just replace ". zip/" with ".zip/"?

Comment: But you asked to only match whitespaces in URLs ending in `zip`. What do you want? Post the exact input and expected output.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew  I've updated my question with the details now.

Comment: See https://regex101.com/r/9oKf4t/1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
\.zip\b[^,]*(*SKIP)(*F)|\s
```

*Details*:

- `\.zip\b[^,]*(*SKIP)(*F)` - match `.zip` followed with a word boundary and then any zero or more non-comma chars and then fail the match and start a new search from the failed position
- `|` - or
- `\s` - a whitespace

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/9oKf4t/2).

Comment: "\s(?=[^,]*\/[^\/,]*zip\b)" from the above link wouldn't select spaces when the zip filename itself contains spaces and also when the path has a different extension, as in the case of the last two URLs. The expected output for the last URLs is: "...,abcd.com/newer%20file/another%20file.zip/some more contents/old sample.txt,abcd.com/newer%20file/another%20file.txt"

Comment: @RahulKunjappa Use this in JavaScript: `text.replace(/(\.zip\b[^,]*)|\s/g, (x,y) => y ? x : " ")`

Comment: @RahulKunjappa In PCRE, you can use `\.zip\b[^,]*(*SKIP)(*F)|\s`, see [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/9oKf4t/2). In .NET, you can use `\s(?<!\.zip\b[^,]*)` (see [this demo](https://regex101.com/r/9oKf4t/3))

Comment: Perfect, it works flawlessly now.

Comment: @RahulKunjappa What exact solution do you need then? What should be in the answer so that the question can be finalized?

Comment: "\.zip\b[^,]*(*SKIP)(*F)|\s", this one worked for me.

Comment: @RahulKunjappa I updated the answer with the PCRE solution.